# Having Strangers' Names in Caller ID Display

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, caller-id, carriers

Tired of not being able to tell who's calling me at all, I ended up putting out the additional monthly cost and getting caller ID display in my phone plan. And since I took it, I... still cannot tell who's calling me most of the time.

Let me explain. When you have a home phone and have caller ID display in your plan, it displays the number of the person calling you as well as the name associated to that number in the phonebook. But that doesn't happen on my mobile phone. Unless it's a contact of mine, it's Unknown / No name that comes with the number.

But the absence of such information makes the feature half as useful as home phone caller ID display (for the same price >_>).

I realise this is more of a network / carrier issue, and that there's probably no way for me, myself, to change it (or is there? :D), but I'm wondering if there's a workaround.

For example, a way for me to create my own phonebook with some names. Of course, I could just add them to my contacts, but adding people who aren't actually contacts would clutter my contacts list a ton. And categories don't really work on my phone. you can't manage them on the phone at all. You need to create contacts at the root of the contacts, and then log in to the Google website with your computer and sort them.

So... Yeah. Is there any remotely convenient way for me to "fix" caller ID display, so I know who is that non-contact who's calling?

**Edit: I forgot to say. I did ask my provider about it. They said the system is different for mobile and home phones and they can't do anything about it.**

My phone:

- Samsung Galaxy Q (SGH-T589W)
- Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread
- Processor: 600MHz Qualcomm MSM7227
- Internal storage: 152 MB
- RAM: 279 MB
- SD card: 2 GB
- Carrier: Videotron

Comment: You could potentially get an app that does a 411 on the number and displays the result but that may be slow/unreliable if it even exists.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yeah. I'm mostly looking for a workaround. Like a "phone book" external to my contacts.

Comment: You DO have two phone books on your Android phone. One is Google contacts that syncs with google.com/contacts. The other is the internal phone book that DOESN'T sync with anything. I am running 2.3.5 and when I add a contact it asks which one I want to create (phone or Google).

Comment: @William But those aren't it two separate places, are they? There are even three places where I can put them. Google account, SIM card, phone. But they'll all still show up in Contacts, and as such, the "pollution" still occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Current Caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webascender.callerid) and it seems to work ok, better if you let it connect with Facebook. It is not perfect but it will help out.

I also use [Reverse Lookup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esmobile.reverselookupfree). It is after the fact, but it does a good job. it will google the number and quickly add it to your phone book if you want.

Neither are going to get you coverage all the time but it is the best I have found.

Comment: But this... requires a mobile Internet connection, right?

Comment: Yes, it will require an internet connection. Just like syncing Google contacts. Your mobile provider is correct there is nothing they can do about missing the caller's name. Mobile phones just don't receive the name, only the number; it has always been that way. I have worked for a small land-line carrier and for Sprint. I have never heard of a "caller ID display" feature from the carrier for mobile phones. Maybe things have changed since I left Sprint 7+ years ago, but I doubt it.

Comment: But does it require an Internet connection whenever I receive a call, or does it have memory, and can it fetch people's names automatically, when I get home, at night, and remember them for the next time they call?

Comment: "unknown" callers will require an internet connection. Current Caller ID does have a "memory" after the first call and I would guess doesn't use the internet to get the name again. Reverse lookup does not have a memory.

Comment: Current Caller ID, can it lookup numbers after they've called? Like, when connected to the Internet, it takes my whole call history, looks each number up and remember their names, and then runs another search for new unknown numbers the next time my phone is connected to the Internet? Because my phone is not online 99 % of the time, so if I need to be connected whenever I get a call, it's quite pointless.

Comment: No, but Reverse Lookup will (manually). It can then store them in your phone book (which i know you don't want to do).

Comment: Listen, I have just suggested what I use. I realize this may not work for everyone. Why don't you just try it and see if it works for you, IT IS FREE. If it doesn't work for you then just remove it from your phone. I don't mean to offend but this conversation about very specific features software I didn't write are quite "pointless". If you were to try it for FREE you would find the answers you are looking for. You didn't specify in your question that "my phone is not online 99 % of the time" so don't then say something is pointless when it needs connectivity to function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was being so specific because my phone's internal memory is nearly full and to try it, I'll need to delete a few apps, and I don't really have any game or such, just daily use stuff, so I wanted to make really sure it did what I needed before making a choice. But you're right. I'm sorry for pestering you with this. Thanks for your patience. ^.^ (PS: I didn't mean to say it was pointless all short ; more like pointless in my case.)

Comment: No problem, I hope it works out for you.